# Sort on an separate table without joining result in pandas?

Tags: sorting, join, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data:

```
fruit = pd.DataFrame({'fruit': ['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'blueberry'], 
                      'colour': ['red', 'orange', 'green', 'black']})

costs = pd.DataFrame({'fruit': ['apple', 'orange', 'blueberry'],
                      'cost': [1.7, 1.4, 2.1]})
```

I want a copy of the `fruit` table sorted by `cost` from the `costs` table, but without the cost column included. What's the best way to do this? It's fine if there's a join in an intermediate step - I'm mostly worried about long-term memory waste.

Comment: ok, `fruit.loc[fruit.merge(costs)['cost'].argsort().argsort()]` works, but maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I would do a left merge and then argsort:

```
In [11]: fruit.merge(costs, how="left")
Out[11]:
   colour      fruit  cost
0     red      apple   1.7
1  orange     orange   1.4
2   green      apple   1.7
3   black  blueberry   2.1
```

*Note: that if you used a different index (for fruits), it will be ignored/replaced with `range(0, len(fruit))`.*

```
In [12]: fruit.merge(costs, how="left")["cost"].argsort()
Out[12]:
0    1
1    0
2    2
3    3
Name: cost, dtype: int64
```

Now reorder using iloc (by position) rather than loc (by label).

```
In [13]: fruit.iloc[fruit.merge(costs, how="left")["cost"].argsort()]
Out[13]:
   colour      fruit
1  orange     orange
0     red      apple
2   green      apple
3   black  blueberry
```

Note: It's important to left merge as an ordinary merge will change the order (!!). It's also more efficient.

---

An alternative, cleaner, but less efficient way:

```
In [21]: fruit.merge(costs).sort("cost").loc[:, fruit.columns]
Out[21]:
   colour      fruit
2  orange     orange
0     red      apple
1   green      apple
3   black  blueberry
```

*Note: In the next pandas, `sort_values` might be preferred over `sort`...*

Answer (score 1):

why don't you merge the columns and then drop the unneeded one

```
pd.merge(fruit , costs).sort_index(by = 'cost').drop('cost' , axis = 1 )
```